# Есть массив [1,2,3,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,3,2,5,5,5,1,1] нужно удалить одинаковые элементы массива, но нельзя использовать new Set на js

Tags: javascript

Есть массив [1,2,3,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,3,2,5,5,5,1,1] нужно удалить одинаковые элементы массива, но нельзя использовать new Set на js

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну так удаляйте. Должно получиться [1,2,3,4,6,5]. В чем собственно вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
можно использовать обьект например.

const arr = [1,2,3,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,3,2,5,5,5,1,1];

function getUniqueArray(arr) {
    const result = {};

    arr.forEach(item => result[item] = item);

    return Object.values(result);
}

getUniqueArray(arr);

 //используется Object.values вместо Object.keys так как ключи превращаются в строки
```

либо вот вариант где на 1 проход результиирующего массива меньше

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,3,2,5,5,5,1,1];

function getUniqueArray(arr) {
    const resultObj = {};
    const resultArr = [];

    arr.forEach(item => {
        if (!resultObj[item]) {
            resultObj[item] = item;
            resultArr.push(item);
        }
    });

    return resultArr;
}

getUniqueArray(arr);
```

Comment: Однострочник `Object.values(arr.reduce((a,b)=>{a[b]=b;return a},{}))`

Comment: @Rudi жесть! В каких случаях может понадобиться такой код?

Comment: Когда нужны уникальные значения массива например.. Почему жесть?)